# Use attached Video as post thumbnail

Tags: wordpress, video, parent-child, attachment

i'm trying to display attached videos of a post as featured-img.

This works great on every parent page with this code:

```
 <?php


            $attachments = get_posts(array(
               'post_type' => 'attachment',
                        'numberposts' => -1,
                        'orderby' => 'menu_order',
                        "order" => "ASC"
                 ));
                 if ($attachments) :
                        $i = 0;
                        foreach ($attachments as $attachment) :
                            $attachment = get_post($attachment->ID);
                            $i++;
                            if ($i > 1)
                                break;
                            if ($attachment->post_mime_type != "video/mp4")
                                continue;
                            else {
                                ?>
                                <video autoplay loop onclick="location.href='<?php the_permalink(); ?>'" muted>
                                    <source src="<?php echo $attachment->guid; ?>" type="video/mp4">
                                </video>
                            <?php

                            }
                            ?>
                        <?php
                        endforeach;
                    endif;
                    ?>
```

Unfortunately i can't get it work on child pages. I think there seems to be a problem with the post_parent attribute. I also tried to change get_posts to
`$attachments = get_children`, but without success.

Any idea on how to solve this?

cheers p

Comment: This doesn't query the current post featured image, but all attachments. And why do you use `get_post` inside the loop?!

Comment: right, as i want to display the first attached video as a featured image in there. the else is 

`<?php
                } else {

                    ?>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('full',array ( 'class' => 'img-responsive') ); ?></a>

    <?php
                }?>`